# SQL - select all IDs in table that has attributed tag

Tags: sql

I've got the following database tables:

Entries:

- id
- name
- {other unimportant attributes}

Tags:

- id
- tag

I want to write a query that selects all entries from the `Entries` table that have all tags in some sort of list. For example, suppose that an entry `A` has tags `[tag1, tag2, tag3]`. I want to select all entires in the `Entries` table that have tags `[tag1,tag2,tag3]`. I've tried using an `INNER JOIN` but this doesn't seem to work - I think `INNER JOIN`s are meant to be used to join two db tables.

here is the query that i've tried:
SELECT entries.name, entries.id FROM entries INNER JOIN tags ON tags.tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2', ...)

Comment: How the tables are connected? Is there a third table that connects between entry_id and tag_id ?

Comment: You can simply make three inner joins to Tags, one for each tag

Comment: Hi. the `id` field in tag is the Entry id

Comment: Thanks @Turo for your response. Fairly new to SQL. Any help with the syntax for the triple inner join would be very helpful!

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you want. Do you want to look what tags exist in the tags table and then select all entries that are tagged with all of these tags? or do you want to look at one entry, see its tags, and then select all entries that have at least these tags (or exactly these tags, no more, no less)? Or do you want to look for entries having some particular tags (only these or at least these)? Or something else still? It would help, did you show some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Please tag your request with the DBMS you are using. SQL dialects differ, so SQL requests should always be tagged with the DBMS in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make three inner joins:

```
SELECT e.* FROM Entries e 
INNER JOIN Tags t1 on e.id = t1.id and t1.tag = 'tag1'  
INNER JOIN Tags t2 on e.id = t2.id and t2.tag = 'tag2'  
INNER JOIN Tags t3 on e.id = t3.id and t3.tag = 'tag3'
```

If the number of tags is variant:

```
SEELCT * from Entries e 
WHERE e.id in (SELECT id from Tags  
                WHERE tag in ('tag1', 'tag2', ...) 
                GROUP BY id
                HAVING count(*) = x) -- x = Length of the list
```

Here in the subquery the ids with all x tags are determined and then the Entries to theses ids are selected

Comment: Is there a better solution? I might have 10 tags that I want to search for, or just 2?

Answer (score 0):

You should join tables based on `id` and put tag comparison in `where` clause

The revised query would be

`SELECT entries.name, entries.id FROM entries INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = entries.id where tags.tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2', ...)`

Comment: Beautiful solution mate! However, I would just add `SELECT DISTINCT` so that each entry doesn't appear multiple times!

Comment: @M.Choy this lists entries that has at least one of the tags, is that right?

Comment: @M. Choy: I seem to have misunderstood your request as well. I thought you were looking for entries that have a set of tags, not at least one of the tags in the set. And in any case this is not a "beautiful solution" (as you see yourself, since you want to fend off the generated duplicates with `DISTINCT` - a typical indicator for a badly written query).

Comment: Oh interesting - Yeah I want to find all `entries` or `entry.id`s that have all of the tags in the list - how would you write that? Edit: I guess my dataset wasn't big enough to test aha